# Not-uniform value scaling?

Tags: c#, transparency

I have a slide input with values 0-100. When I change it, the opacity of my button changes to value/100 (because alpha is 0-1). So at position 50%, the alpha will be 0.5.

I'd like to make the value to change in a non-uniform way: to e.g. 75% of the slider width, I want to have a 0.5 actual alpha value, and when it exceeds that 75%, it smoothly scales up to 1.0 alpha until the restant 25% of the slider (with a big, noticeable change from 74% and 76%).

Is it possible using some kind of scale?

I'm using C# (even though it should be the same in any language).

Comment: To the guy that deleted his answer: it worked flawlessly! So please post back your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: OK. I deleted it because perhaps it does not have the desirable jump at 75% :).

Comment: Well, after all, the idea is very clever. Doesn't do a very big jump, but nonetheless, works. And fits my needs. :)

Comment: If you replace `150` with something bigger, e.g. `300`, you'll get a jump. Then `74%` corresponds to about `0.25` alpha, and `75%` to `0.5`. Just 2 cents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would this work?

```
double x = // a value between 0 and 100
double alpha = (x < 75)? x / 150 : x / 50 - 1;
```